# Where the idea of Runge-Kutta methods come from

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The family of explicit Runge–Kutta methods is given by
$$
y_{n+1}=y_n+\sum_{i=1}^{s}{b_i k_i},
$$
where
$$\begin{align}
k_1 & =hf(t_n,y_n),\\
k_2 & =hf(t_n+c_2 h, y_n+a_{21}k_1),\\
k_3 & =hf(t_n+c_3 h, y_n+a_{31}k_1+a_{32}k_2),\\
\vdots\\
k_3 & =hf(t_n+c_s h, y_n+a_{s1}k_1+a_{s2}k_2+a_{s3}k_3+\cdots+a_{s,s-1}k_{s-1})
\end{align}$$

But how Runge and Kutta achieved it? Where this formula come from and what are $k_i\text{'s}$?

Comment: Formula comes from Taylor expansion. You should study that:   (http://www.ss.ncu.edu.tw/~lyu/lecture_files_en/lyu_NSSP_Notes/Lyu_NSSP_AppendixC.pdf).

Comment: I remember there's a pretty good explanation in George Simmons' book on differential equations.

Comment: @MJD "We will not drive the method, but only describe its use" (Simmons, Differential Equations with Historical Notes, pages: 69-71)

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken.

Comment: Why do we set c1=0?